# How to manipulate Query Output in URL?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In this website when you select a category and input a zip code it matches you with the closest vendors based upon the geographical location of the zip code.  The method used in the form is GET so it passes the query into the URL.

```
example.com/contractor_page.php?cat=2&zip=75000
```

I tried looking for `contractor_page.php` from the `main_directory` and its nowhere to be found. I also looked in `sub_folders` and dug through all of the code and could find no references linking this `.php` file at all.

Do form action files not need to exist at all? I tried manipulating the name of the form action to see if it would reflect in the URL after searching but it does not it continues to stay the same as `contractor_page.php` and its driving me freaking nuts.

I was hoping to just bypass all of this and do it through htaccess but all attempts I've made looking at multiple sites and questions that relate on this site did not work.

I want to change it from:

```
example.com/contractor_page.php?cat=2&zip=75000
```

To:

```
example.com/Dallas-Fort-Worth/HVAC
```

where `zip=7500` = `dallas-fort-worth`

and `cat=2` = `HVAC`

The current `.htaccess` file looks like this.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# Redirect /index.php to / (optional, but recommended I guess)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php
RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

# Run everything else but real files through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   ^cat=2&zip=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^contractor_page.php$ /Dallas-Fort-Worth/ [NC,R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

The header.php file has this code

```
<?php
  if($uri == "contractor_page.php") {
  ob_start();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cat'] = $_GET['cat'];
    $_SESSION['zip'] = $_GET['zip'];

  } else {
   session_start();
  }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
```

And the top part for the form code is here:

```
<form action="contractor_page.php" method="get">
     <div class="form-group">
```

interior page that displays results

```
 <div class="inner-cont-wrap">
            <?php echo $content; ?>
            <?php if($uri == "contractor_page.php"): ?>
               <div class="yellow-header">
                   <h2>Register Once And You're Covered</h2>
                   <span class="rbn left-ribbon"></span>
                   <a href="#" class="reg-now" onclick="registration=window.open('registration_form.php', 'registration', 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, dependent=yes, width=750, height=650, screenX=250, left=250, screenY=100, top=100'); return true;">Register Now</a>
                   <span class="rbn right-ribbon"></span>
                   <p>By Our $10,000 Guarantee!</p>
               </div><!-- end yellow header -->
                <?php  include('_GCL_sc1ipt5/contractor.php'); ?>
            <?php elseif($uri == "contractor_spe.php"): ?>
                <?php include ('_GCL_sc1ipt5/spec_contractor_inc.php'); ?>
            <?php elseif($uri == "contractor_list.php"): ?>
                <?php include ('_GCL_sc1ipt5/contractor_by_category.php'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

How would I go about making this work? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule just below `RewriteBase` line:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cat=2&zip=75000$ 
RewriteRule ^contractor_page\.php$ /Dallas-Fort-Worth/HVAC? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: That works but unfortunately it poses more problems.  The whole site is dynamically done.  It broke the results page when it changed it because of this code (added in the main question)

Comment: Well I can only help to redirect URL the way you've described in question. Then your code must be able to handle `http://domain.com/Dallas-Fort-Worth/HVAC` correctly.